# Does Windows Task Scheduler overlaps with time trigger

Tags: task-scheduler

I have created a time trigger for a task that would run daily at 7 pm during, weekdays only. But I also need to set a trigger where it runs at 7 pm, at the 1st to 6th day of the month regardless if it's weekends or weekdays. Will the 7pm run for weekdays, overlap with 1st to 6th day run at 7pm?

Comment: There's an option to kill the process if it's already running, or to not start it again, when setting up scheduled tasks. Also, have you tested and observed?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, it seems to work even with over lapping. Might probably because of the software's capability to run the program, one at a time. I also tried a simple task like opening a txt file. It only opened once

Here's the pic of the trigger: https://pasteboard.co/fsaakj9e7QwA.png

I did it like this for the the notepad testing. Not sure if I did this right(it's monday on my Timezone btw), but testing this only opened the txt file once.